# Show different form depending of the gender selected at the first question

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show a form regarding the first form question answer.
Here, in the first form we select the gender and depending of the choice of the gender in the first form, i would like to make the first form disappear and show the new matching form: form 1 for female and form 2 for male in this example.

I'm trying to use this jquery code but its not work

```js
$("#selectgender").on("change", function() {
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show().siblings().hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="selectgender" action="">

<h1>Select gender:</h1>

Gender:
<label class="imgradio" value="form_name1">
  <input type="radio" name="Genre" value="female" checked>female
</label>

<label class="imgradio" value="form_name2">
  <input type="radio" name="Genre" value="male">male
</label>

</form>


<form name="form_name1" id="regForm" style="display:none" action="">
<!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
<div class="tab">
... female questions
</div>
</form>

<form name="form_name2" id="regForm" style="display:none" action="">
<!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
<div class="tab">
... male questions
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. On `showTab(n)` hide or show the respective fields depending on the value of the gender input.

Comment: Thanks @ariel. edited. i tried this but seems not work

Comment: out of curiosity, what kinds of different questions are you going to ask?  i can't think of much that makes sense to gate on gender; you might want to ask a more specific question about what you actually want

Comment: Why change from `<div class="tab">` to `form`? You broke the code.

Comment: the question will be related to fitness/ health topic so its differ depending of gender but not only this, i have to display different photo for each gender . Thanks to ask @Eevee

Comment: thanks @ariel but still have an issue after update

Answer (score 0):

Below a minimal working example on how to access the radio button value with jQuery. However, you have some serious logical problems in the structure of your code. Please consider:

1. Using the "onChange"-Event, the user has to toggle at least once the gender in order to see the next form.
2. With the current setup it's not possible to see the questions for women because you're hiding the gender radio buttons. I don't think that's the desired behavior.
3. Making one single form, but depending on the gender, you can display different questions.

```js
$("#selectgender").on("change", function() {
  var gender = $('input[name=Genre]:checked').val()
  $("#" + gender +"Form").show().siblings().hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="selectgender" action="">

<h1>Select gender:</h1>

Gender:
<label class="imgradio" value="form_name1">
  <input type="radio" name="Genre" value="female" checked>female
</label>

<label class="imgradio" value="form_name2">
  <input type="radio" name="Genre" value="male">male
</label>

</form>


<form name="form_name1" id="femaleForm" style="display:none" action="">
<!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
<div class="tab">
... female questions
</div>
</form>

<form name="form_name2" id="maleForm" style="display:none" action="">
<!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
<div class="tab">
... male questions
</div>
</form>
```